# Converting An Objective-C AppDelegate Category Class To A Swift Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate

We have a project built with Cordova. However we are writing a lot of code in Swift. Due to a number of Xcode Bridging Header bugs too long to get into, we need to re-write our AppDelegate.m into Swift.

That went just fine.

However, there is a plugin for Cordova for [push notifications](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2Bnotification.m).

This plugin has us install another file that is a Category of type AppDelegate.

The top of its header file is as following:

```
@implementation AppDelegate (notification)
```

There are no categories in Swift, there are extensions. My question is this: When converting this file to Swift, should I just delete this file, and add it's extension to the existing AppDelegate file, or do a I create an AppDelegate+notification.swift class and just write?

```
extension AppDelegate {

//code

}
```

Basically I'm a little confused why there would be a separate file that adds functionality to the AppDelegate. Why wouldn't they just 'extend' it in the first place and now I'm not sure how to convert this AppDelegate+notification.m file to Swift.

**UPDATE**

I removed the main.m file, the AppDelegate.m/.h, and the AppDelegate+notification.m/.h file and converted them into the corresponding Swift AppDelegate files inside a new AppDelegate.swift file and it worked.

Comment: I found this post because I am trying to find out exactly how to convert a Cordova Objective-C AppDelegate file to Swift. Could you give any details about how you went about doing that?

Comment: Just re-write the objc methods from any delegate classes you have as swift classes. They used Swizzling, because they wanted extend the App delegate. You dont need to use that because you will just put it all in your AppDelegate.swift. So just convert the methods in the app delegates to one AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension in swift is similar to Category in Objective-c. You can add more methods, customized init ... to the extension.

To add extension to AppDelegate, we don't have to create AppDelegate+notification.swift but you add an extension AppDelegate section in AppDelegate.swift file. Take attention that extension does not have name as Category in Objective-C. But of course, you can create multiples extension of AppDelegate, give it a //MARK: to distinguish

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

```
//MARK: extension Hello
extension AppDelegate {
    func sayHello() {
       NSLog("hello")
    }

}

//MARK: extension goodbye
extension AppDelegate {
    func sayGoodbye() {
        NSLog("goodbye")
    }

}
```